# Regex pattern search starts with 2 letters OR 2 numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing a javascript function to detect a correct entry into the database before sending it.  The variable must start with either 2 digits OR 2 letters followed by 2 more letters then 3 digits.  I can make each regex work independently but I want to do this in one statement. I've tried `/^[A-Z]{2}|^[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{2}\d{3}$/` with no luck.

```
 var valL = /^[A-Z]{2}[A-Z]{2}\d{3}$/;letter
    var valj = /^[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{2}\d{2}$/;digits
```

Comment: [A-Z0-9]{2} allows A9 too

Comment: @adeneo that will match A3 or 3B, i think he wants like AA or 33

Comment: I did try that also, but it allows the entry to start with 1 digit and 1 letter, which is not allowed.  It must be 2 digits or 2 letters, unless your able to produce that answer?

Comment: /^([A-Z]{2}|[0-9]{2})[A-Z]{2}\d{3}$/

Comment: @adeneo That does the same thing - you need to put the `{2}` with each character set

Comment: @Ian - yeah, forgot to add the length limiter inside the group, but the right answer is already posted, so I give up

Comment: /^\w{2}[A-Za-z]{2}\d{3}$/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to group your alternation.

```
/^([A-Z]{2}|[0-9]{2})[A-Z]{2}\d{3}$/
```

otherwise you match only the left or the right side of the alternation.

Comment: And it might need `a-z` in those character sets too, but I guess that's up to the OP (or use the `i` flag)

Comment: @stema it works perfect, I just couldn't remember how to group and was using [], this is why I love this site, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Following regex should work:

```
/^(?:[A-Z]{2}|\d{2})[A-Z]{2}\d{3}$/i
```

Comment: Well, your original wouldn't work, and through your many edits to attempt to fix it, I gave up keeping track. Now it's basically the same as the other answer. I'll at least remove my downvote

Comment: @Ian: Thanks so much for your comment. Didn't really make too many edits, 1 of which was cosmetic to change `[0-9]` to `\d`.

Comment: Well now I forget the history of edits (since we can't see edits in the first 5 minutes), but there was something I didn't like. Like I said, I removed my downvote at least, as it looks fine now :)

Comment: @Ian: Totally appreciate your gesture.

Comment: @anubhava I'm not sure what the ?: does?

Comment: ?: is non capturing group. In this example square brackets are used to group 2: digits or letters but using ?: doesn't populate $1